# Append to file names in a loop with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Desired functionality

```
file1.txt ->  file1.txt.deploy
file2.txt ->  file2.txt.deploy
```

Attempt #82

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + ".deploy" }
}
```

`Cannot evaluate parameter NewName because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change `{}` with `()` in `-newname` parameter value.

Comment: Or pipe directly to `Rename-Item` and skip `Foreach-Object` entirely. It's not necessary in this case.

Comment: Why would you use `{}` over `()`? I know the first is a script block, but why is it not appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ForEach-Object` you need to pipe in the actual object with `$_`:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item $_ -NewName { $_.Name + ".deploy" }
}
```

Or just skip the `ForEach-Object` as BartekB mentions in comments:

```
Get-ChildItem |  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + ".deploy" }
```